# Why does this render say that it requires a semi colon?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm new to react and I'm trying to figure out why this render statement says that is requires a semicolon.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/firestore';

function test() {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Display</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
  } 
  

  export default test;
```

Comment: What is saying it needs a semicolon, and where? It's probably just the settings on your linter, and in that case, you should put the semicolon where it says - I imagine at the end of your `test` function

Comment: Components should begin with an upper case first letter (`Test`). The `render` method is for *class* components, this is a function. This is a syntax error since you're not declaring a method `render`, but calling a function that doesn't exist and adding a body in a place that doesn't work. Are you trying to use a function or class component?

Answer (score 0):

`test` is a function component, you don't need a render method for a function component. Just remove the `render` method and the code should work.

Read more about function components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Answer (score -1):

Most ECMAScript statements and declarations must be terminated with a semicolon. Such semicolons may always appear explicitly in the source text. For convenience, however, such semicolons may be omitted from the source text in certain situations. These situations are described by saying that semicolons are automatically inserted into the source code token stream in those situations.

In your case, ES6 is being used through babel. It's a transpiler and it may add the missed semicolons in the process of transpiling the source text to native JS.